# Un-install internet explorer before re-installing windows xp

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, reinstall

I wanted to re-install windows xp in my system for repairing purpose. But before that one of my tutorials suggested to un-install internet explorer. I don't know why ?

If someone knows the exact reason for it...........

Answer (score 1):

Removing IE from Windows XP can have unpredictable consequences and as far as I'm aware it's  not generally a good thing to do. Having said that, if you feel you absolutely must remove this component, you can do so via a number of methods.

You can create a preconfigured image of XP with whatever components you wish by using nLite:

http://www.nliteos.com/

Support can be found here: http://www.msfn.org/board/forum/89-nlite/

For post installation removal, take a look a XPlite:

http://www.litepc.com/xplite.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

On my friend's suggestion I have already bought Stellar Phoenix Windows Data Recovery Software to handle any data loss circumstances.